# convert columns of spark data frame to json

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame of which contains statistical description of a data frame.

`x=summaryDataFrame
+-------+---+
|summary| c1|
+-------+---+
|  count|  3|
|   mean|3.0|
| stddev|2.0|
|    min|  1|
|    max|  5|
+-------+---+`

now i want to convert it into a json of format 

`{"c1":{"mean":3,"count":3,"stddev":2,...}}`

also I can have n number of columns in `x`. Please help me implement this I am very new to scala.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How about using `toJSON` operation of `DataFrame`?

Comment: I tried that but it gives me ```{"summary":"count", "c1":3}{"summary":"mean", "c1":3}``` format

Comment: You might have to use Scala JSON libraries to convert into required format. Spark-Scala API's may not be able to provide anything readily available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can approach it:

```scala
val funs = Seq("count", "mean", "stddev", "min", "max")

def makeExprs(c: String, funs: Seq[String]) = funs.map(f => s"$f($c) AS $f")

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (32.0, 31.0, 14.0), (3.6, 2.8, 0.0), (4.5, 5.0, -1.2)
)).toDF

df.columns.flatMap(c => df
  .selectExpr(makeExprs(c, funs): _*)
  .toJSON
  .map(r => s"""{"$c": $r}""").collect
)
```